# Regular expression to extract and split text from one column in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a data-set with two column - one is date and other one is data and the value is as below

```
date                                    data
1-1-2019     [[{'user_id': 1111, 'joining_date': '2011-01-01', 'country': 'EN'}]]
```

My question is how do I split this value and create a new column (and get the prefix as column name) as below?

```
date       userid            joining_date          country
1-1-2019    1111              2011-01-01           EN
```

Comment: How do you end up with the initial data frame in the first place?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
# setup
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "date": ['1-1-2019', '1-1-2019'],
    "data": [[{'user_id': 1111, 'joining_date': '2011-01-01', 'country': 'EN'}],
             [{'user_id': 1234, 'joining_date': '2017-01-01', 'country': 'FR'}]]
})

# core logic
df1 = pd.DataFrame(df['data'].apply(lambda _: _[0]).values.tolist())
df1['date'] = df['date']
```

Output:

```
    country joining_date    user_id date
0   EN      2011-01-01      1111    1-1-2019
1   FR      2017-01-01      1234    1-1-2019
```

Comment: Note that this won't work in the case where there's **multiple** dictionaries in each list in the `data` column. E.g. `[{'user_id': 1111, 'joining_date': '2011-01-01', 'country': 'EN'}, {'user_id': 1111, 'joining_date': '2011-01-01', 'country': 'EN'}]`. If this is the case there are simple workarounds, let me know.

Comment: Hi Andy, yes, the above solution can only capture userid while doesn't include country and joining_date, any workaround for the question pls ?